# Print writer format

Tags: java, format, printwriter

I have a list with several objects each containing three `strings`, how should I format the output (in `outfile.format()`) to make it look like in the sample output below?

```
public void save() {
        try {

            PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter
                             (new BufferedWriter
                             (new FileWriter("reg_out.txt")));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        { 
            outfile.format("???", list.get(i).getLastName(),
                                        list.get(i).getFirstName(),
                                        list.get(i).getNumber());
        }

            outfile.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Sample output in reg_out.txt:

```
Allegrettho     Albert          0111-27543
Brio            Britta          0113-45771
Cresendo        Crister         0111-27440
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
outfile.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%n", list.get(i).getLastName(),
                                        list.get(i).getFirstName(),
                                        list.get(i).getNumber());
```

see java.util.Formatter API for details

Comment: there should be no spaces after numbers, NEW LINE should follow it. Is it possible that getNumber returns a string with a tailing space?

Comment: You're correct, I don't what happened, there are no spaces.